# PUT parameters not working in python / google app engine

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, web-applications, put

i'm working on a simple RESTful webservice with python with the webapp framework on the google app engine.

Basically i'm sending all request via AJAX/jquery - for POST it works like a charm, but when I'm sending data with PUT, the parameters are empty / not processed.

this is my PUT:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/boxes",
        data: { name: this.name, archived: this.archived  },
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });
```

firebug saids i'm putting:

```
Parameter   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
archived    false
name    123112323asdasd
```

but using this python code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util, template
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api.datastore_types import *
from django.utils import simplejson as json

import cgi
import datetime

class BoxHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

def post(self): #working
    print "test"
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get("name"))

def put(self):
    print "test" #not working
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get("name"))
```

will just return

```
test
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

so .. hm, is there anything i'm missing here?

cheers,
Martin

Comment: Can you put your Python code into context? What is the type of self.request?

Comment: inserted the whole class - hope that helps - thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `put` method in your code is correctly invoked because as you can see, `test` is printed;
what is not working is the parameter parsing, this problem is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=719) in the `webob` class.

You could try to parse the request.body to extract the query string.

```
def put(self):
    print "test"
    name = parse_body_to_extract_your_parameter(self.request.body)
    self.response.out.write(name)
```